# Custom deserializer fails when using positional operator

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I'm creating a custom serializer for a list of elements, the idea being that I will avoid deserializing some elements based on their values.

This works fine for most read / update calls, i.e.

```cs
await collection.InsertOneAsync(entry);
await collection.FindAsync(x => x.Id == entry.Id);
await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(x => x.Id == entry.Id, Builders<Outer>.Update.Set(x => x.Value, 5));
```

but when I do an update call using the positional operator,

```cs
var filter = Builders<Outer>.Filter.Where(x => x.Elements.Any(e => e.Id == elementId));
var update = Builders<Outer>.Update.Set(x => x.Elements[-1].Value, 5);
await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
```

it fails with the following error:

```cs
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Property 'System.String Id' is not defined for type 'System.Object'
Parameter name: property
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression expression, MemberInfo member)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Update(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.BinderHelper.BindWhere(PipelineExpression pipeline, IBindingContext bindingContext, LambdaExpression lambda)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.EmbeddedPipeline.MethodCallBinders.AnyBinder.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, EmbeddedPipelineBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.MethodInfoMethodCallBinder`1.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, TBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.CompositeMethodCallBinder`1.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, TBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.EmbeddedPipeline.EmbeddedPipelineBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBindingContext parent)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Visit(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate[TDocument](Expression`1 predicate, IBsonSerializer`1 parameterSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOneAndUpdateOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions`2 options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindOneAndUpdateAsync[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass55_0`1.<FindOneAndUpdateAsync>b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoFiltering.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\jeroen.vannevel\source\repos\MongoFiltering\MongoFiltering\Program.cs:line 51
   at MongoFiltering.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

I have minified it to the following sample. From what I can tell, your custom deserializer doesn't actually need to do any work -- just the presence of it breaks the filtering clause.

Below are the models I use and the empty custom serializer. I have created an [MCVE here](https://gist.github.com/Vannevelj/f36f3e5291f878bad12cda810afe0f60) which uses Mongo2Go to build an on-the-fly mongo daemon -- you can just execute it.

```
public class Outer
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }

        [BsonSerializer(typeof(ElementsSerializer))]
        public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class ElementsSerializer : EnumerableSerializerBase<List<Element>>
    {
        public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, List<Element> value) => base.Serialize(context, args, value);

        public override List<Element> Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) => base.Deserialize(context, args);

        protected override void AddItem(object accumulator, object item) => ((List<Element>)accumulator).Add((Element)item);
        protected override object CreateAccumulator() => new List<Element>();
        protected override IEnumerable EnumerateItemsInSerializationOrder(List<Element> value) => value;
        protected override List<Element> FinalizeResult(object accumulator) => (List<Element>)accumulator;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. It looks like there are two base classes to inherit from: `EnumerableSerializerBase<TValue>` and `EnumerableSerializerBase<TValue, TItem>`. 
If you use the former (which I did), it will use [a simple `object` deserializer](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/85776cfc76b41ba03682e2d35e65b531c7bd6cdb/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/EnumerableSerializerBase.cs#L67). Using the other overload, however, [uses the generic deserializer](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/85776cfc76b41ba03682e2d35e65b531c7bd6cdb/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/EnumerableSerializerBase.cs#L248).

The final deserializer looks like this and it works as intended:

```
public class ElementsSerializer : EnumerableSerializerBase<List<Element>, Element>
{
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, List<Element> value) => base.Serialize(context, args, value);
    public override List<Element> Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) => base.Deserialize(context, args);
    protected override object CreateAccumulator() => new List<Element>();
    protected override List<Element> FinalizeResult(object accumulator) => (List<Element>)accumulator;
    protected override void AddItem(object accumulator, Element item) => ((List<Element>)accumulator).Add(item);
    protected override IEnumerable<Element> EnumerateItemsInSerializationOrder(List<Element> value) => value;
}
```

Without this, the `EmbeddedPipelineBinder` [will register](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/85776cfc76b41ba03682e2d35e65b531c7bd6cdb/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Processors/EmbeddedPipeline/EmbeddedPipelineBinder.cs#L97) an expression-to-be-replaced of our lambda value with the result of the beforementioned serializer. Aka, we would replace all usages of the `Element` lambda value with a document of type `object`. When our lambda then tries to access the `.Id` property, it complains that it doesn't have that property on type `object` -- as is correct.

The reason why this only showed up when trying to access a nested collection is, I assume, because the initial level [uses the `PipelineBinder`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/85776cfc76b41ba03682e2d35e65b531c7bd6cdb/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Processors/Pipeline/PipelineBinder.cs) (notice the lack of *Embedded*) which does not have this special array deserialization logic.